# Create a List View by Quarter

Tags: calendar, view

I have a list of deliverables in SharePoint 2010 and would like to create a view of deliverables due in a calendar quarter. However, rather than the standard calendar quarters (Jan-Mar, Apr-Jun, Jul-Sep, Oct-Dec), I need the views grouped by Sep-Nov, Dec-Feb, Mar-May, Jun-Aug. Is there a way I can create this type of view. Thx much!

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, create a Calculated Column that figures out the quarter, and then create a view that groups on that column.

In more detail:

- Create a new Calculated Column with a name such as "Quarter".
- Add the formula below.
- Create a View (or edit the existing View) and group on the new Calculated Column.

The formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(DueDate),"No Date",
  IF( OR(MONTH(DueDate)=9,
        MONTH(DueDate)=10,
        MONTH(DueDate)=11),"Qtr 1",
   IF( OR(MONTH(DueDate)=12,
           MONTH(DueDate)=1,
           MONTH(DueDate)=2),"Qtr 2",
     IF( OR(MONTH(DueDate)=3,
             MONTH(DueDate)=4,
             MONTH(DueDate)=5),"Qtr 3",
"Qtr 4"))))
```

[image]