# Create Sharepoint View Filtered by Current Quarter in sharepoint lists/Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, sharepoint-views

I'd like to create dates for the projects we are working on in our company, and it has to be **filtered by quarters and calculated columns**.

Can any one help me with that? Please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your projects have completion date and if you want to find the quarter using that, then you can use the below approach and steps,

This you can achieve by creating a calculated column with the below formula:

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(MONTH([CompletedDate]))>=1,VALUE(MONTH([CompletedDate]))<4),"Q1",(IF(AND(VALUE(MONTH([CompletedDate]))>=4,VALUE(MONTH([CompletedDate]))<7),"Q2",(IF(AND(VALUE(MONTH([CompletedDate]))>=7,VALUE(MONTH([CompletedDate]))<10),"Q3","Q4")))))
```

**Note**: CompletedDate is the date of project completion

Once you create this column all the reports will be divided in to 4 sections Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4. Now you can create 4 views with the filter on calculated column equals to Q1 to Q4.

For more information, follow the below URL's

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/817d11fd-b932-4e72-ae10-5df0c2634802/sharepoint-custom-list-quarterly-view?forum=sharepointgeneral

[Create a List View by Quarter](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242161/create-a-list-view-by-quarter)

Comment: I think there might be an error in the formula. It doesn't work. I think we should use [columns] for columns. please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I highly appreciate the help, but would it be possible to create a view the shows/filter the current quarter?

Comment: If you column name has space, then the name has to be included within [column name], but in the example which I gave, the column name doesn't have space so [] is not needed.

Comment: updated the answer with []

Comment: Could you please create a new question to create a view the shows/filter the current quarter?, so that all users of this site will get to know this requirement and will give you many approaches.

Comment: if you find my answer useful, kindly upvote and accept it as answer, so that it will help others too.